# HTML5 video + Ajax + IE = bad performance?

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, internet-explorer, html5-video

I'm currently working on a big web-app that will be used in a local network :

- One page, playing up to 12 videos (SD). Flash or HTML5, I have the choice.
- On the same page, an interval (every 800 ms) is calling a Php script (~30ms execution time) with Ajax.

Everything works fine but ... Internet Explorer :)

In Chrome or Firefox, with flash or HTML5, ajax requests takes 35 to 60ms when 12 videos are playing.

In IE11 (or 10), ajax requests takes 100ms per playing video. It's really a huge problem for me.
If there is 12 playing videos, the request take 1.2s.

Maybe someone knows a way to make those requests faster in IE ?

Thanks !

---

Here is very simple code I use for my tests :

**HTML / Javascript**

```
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
            setInterval(function(){testAjax()},800); 
    });

        function testAjax(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "./AjaxTest.php",
                cache:false
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- this x12 -->
    <video autoplay>
        <source type="video/mp4" src="video.MP4"> <!-- Change video to a WEBM file when testing in IE -->
    </video>
</body>
```

**AjaxTest.php**

```
<?php
usleep(30000);
?>
```

Comment: Why exactly are you calling the PHP file every 800ms?

Comment: In short : the Php Script look a schedule in a database and says "Start a new video NOW" or "Stop this one NOW". And it have to be very precise :(

Comment: Can you clarify - is it one 100ms request for each of the 12 videos every 800ms? or a single batch request for all 12 that takes 1.2 seconds?

Comment: 1 request every 800ms. And this request take 100ms*number_video to be done in IE (for a total of 1.2s if there is 12 videos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Months later, the same problem is back !
With big amount of videos playing (up to 21 ! :D), requests in IE takes 30-60 seconds !

I finally know why :
Internet Explorer restrict the amount of active HTTP request you can have simultaneously for a server.
In my case, every steamers are on the same server. It means that my requests are put in a queue and can sometime wait 60s before beeing sends.

The IE restriction can be removed, this blog post explain how to do it (it's super easy) :
http://www.pallareviews.com/1186/increase-internet-explorer-download-limit/

Answer (score 1):

For this HTML5 provides a feature called "Web worker" to run your script in background independent of the requests made by the current pages.

For reference here is the link [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp).

Comment: Ajax request in a worker is not a very good thing to do from what I've readed, isn't it ? I will try. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Tests done : it's a lot better ! It now take 50-300ms instead of 1.2s for 12 videos.